# custom auth guards in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have multiple entities in my application that need to be authenticated. So I defined multiple guards to do so:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],

    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
    'partner' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'partners',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

Then in my Login controllers I have the following condition:

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

when I try to do so (even though it's written in the docs) I get an error telling me that "method attempt does not exist".

So I try defining the guard method on the controller (also like the docs) like this:

```
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

authentication still doesn't work with the right credentials (I tried to check what guard the Auth facade was using before the attempt using dd(Auth::guard()) and it was the default web guard.

I tried removing the web guard from the default guards array in auth config. didn't work.

I also tried config:clear and rerunning the server but nothing worked!

I am out of ideas. I know that I can write my own simple login, but why reinvent the wheel, and I was following the docs to the letter. help.

Comment: what errors do you have and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: that guard(driver) doesn't have an `attempt` method

Comment: As it says it does not have that function, write your owm implemengation